# How to pass variable to asp MenuItem

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a ASP Menu in my webpage:

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
<Items>
   <asp:MenuItem  Text="" Value="home" />
....
</Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

All I want is: The Text tag of MenuItem displays the user name: `Session["user"].Tostring()`

with code behind:

```
IDMenuItem.Text= Session["user"].Tostring();
```

and

```
<asp:MenuItem  Text="//the user name will be displayed here" Value="home" />
```

But there is no `ID` tag in `MenuItem`. Help???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
Menu.Items[0].Text = Session["user"].ToString();
```

Comment: No problem, glad you've got a solution.